# JSON Parsing, issue with Nested JSON structure

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

Let's say we have this [URL](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTH,XRP&tsyms=USD), I'm using [CodableAlamofire](https://github.com/Otbivnoe/CodableAlamofire) to fetch and parse the JSON response.

For the above URL response I've created following Codable classes.

```
struct CoinList: Codable {
    let raw: Raw
    let display: Display

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case raw = "RAW"
        case display = "DISPLAY"
    }
}

struct Display: Codable {
    let usd: [String: Usd]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case usd = "USD"
    }
}

struct Raw: Codable {
    let usd: [String: Usd]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case usd = "USD"
    }
}

struct Usd: Codable {
    let type, market, fromsymbol, tosymbol: String
    let flags: String
    let price: Double
    let lastupdate: Int
    let lastvolume, lastvolumeto: Double
    let lasttradeid: String
    let volumeday, volumedayto, volume24Hour, volume24Hourto: Double
    let openday, highday, lowday, open24Hour: Double
    let high24Hour, low24Hour: Double
    let lastmarket: String
    let change24Hour, changepct24Hour, changeday, changepctday: Double
    let supply, mktcap, totalvolume24H, totalvolume24Hto: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type = "TYPE"
        case market = "MARKET"
        case fromsymbol = "FROMSYMBOL"
        case tosymbol = "TOSYMBOL"
        case flags = "FLAGS"
        case price = "PRICE"
        case lastupdate = "LASTUPDATE"
        case lastvolume = "LASTVOLUME"
        case lastvolumeto = "LASTVOLUMETO"
        case lasttradeid = "LASTTRADEID"
        case volumeday = "VOLUMEDAY"
        case volumedayto = "VOLUMEDAYTO"
        case volume24Hour = "VOLUME24HOUR"
        case volume24Hourto = "VOLUME24HOURTO"
        case openday = "OPENDAY"
        case highday = "HIGHDAY"
        case lowday = "LOWDAY"
        case open24Hour = "OPEN24HOUR"
        case high24Hour = "HIGH24HOUR"
        case low24Hour = "LOW24HOUR"
        case lastmarket = "LASTMARKET"
        case change24Hour = "CHANGE24HOUR"
        case changepct24Hour = "CHANGEPCT24HOUR"
        case changeday = "CHANGEDAY"
        case changepctday = "CHANGEPCTDAY"
        case supply = "SUPPLY"
        case mktcap = "MKTCAP"
        case totalvolume24H = "TOTALVOLUME24H"
        case totalvolume24Hto = "TOTALVOLUME24HTO"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        type = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        market = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .market)
        fromsymbol = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .fromsymbol)
        tosymbol = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .tosymbol)
        flags = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .flags)

        price = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .price)
        lastvolume = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .lastvolume)
        lastvolumeto = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .lastvolumeto)
        lastupdate = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .lastupdate)

        if let value = try? values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .lasttradeid) {
            lasttradeid = String(value)
        } else {
            lasttradeid = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lasttradeid)
        }

        volumeday = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .volumeday)
        volumedayto = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .volumedayto)
        volume24Hour = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .volume24Hour)
        volume24Hourto = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .volume24Hourto)
        openday = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .openday)
        highday = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .highday)
        lowday = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .lowday)
        open24Hour = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .open24Hour)
        high24Hour = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .high24Hour)
        low24Hour = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .low24Hour)

        lastmarket = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastmarket)

        change24Hour = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .change24Hour)
        changepct24Hour = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .changepct24Hour)
        changeday = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .changeday)
        changepctday = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .changepctday)

        supply = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .supply)
        mktcap = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .mktcap)
        totalvolume24H = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .totalvolume24H)
        totalvolume24Hto = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .totalvolume24Hto)
    }
}
```

After successful response, I'm unable to parse the JSON, I studied a lot on nested JSON parsing with Swift Codable but still unable to get success.

Please help me to parse the above JSON response with nested JSON structure, like say **Display** and **Raw** object have all properties of **Usd**.

I think there is some minor mistake I'm doing.

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've created JSON file for the response and parsing it,

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(CoinList.self, from: data)
        print(result)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Error is this,

[image]

JSON structure is like this,

[image]

Please find my my web api call,

```
    Alamofire.request(TickerRouter.PriceMultiFull(params: params))
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString { responseData in                
            let data = responseData.value?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "/").data(using: .utf8)
            if responseData.error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({ AnyKey(stringValue: $0.last!.stringValue.lowercased())!})
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
                let result = try? decoder.decode(CoinList.self, from: data!)
                success(result!)
            } else {
                let msg = "Something went wrong. Please try again later"
                failure(msg)
            }
    }
```

result is nil here, it is working with local json file. :(

Comment: You can save yourself so much time writing boilerplate code by just using a custom `KeyDecodingStrategy` to make your key become uppercase

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: @rmaddy I've created json file for the following response, Please find my updated answer for parsing json file, error is screenshot attached in question. please find it.

Comment: The second and third lines of the struct thing don't look correct.

Comment: @ElTomato can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @PPL You are not using `BTH` and `XRP` objects to get the `USD`. I think this is one of the reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance you will notice that the member types in the `USD` dictionary for `raw` and `display` are widely different, so a single struct for both doesn't work.

The root object is (the `String` keys are the `BTH` and `XRP` symbols)

```
struct CoinList: Codable {
    let raw: [String: Raw]
    let display: [String: Display]
}
```

The `Raw` and `Display` structs contain the `usd` key and the appropriate struct

```
struct Raw: Codable {
    let usd: USDRaw
}

struct Display: Codable {
    let usd: USDDisplay
}
```

The `USDRaw` and `USDDisplay` structs contain all data, `lastupdate` in `USDRaw` will be decoded as `Date`

```
struct USDRaw: Codable {
    let type, market, flags, fromsymbol, tosymbol: String
    let price : Double
    let lastupdate: Date
    let lastvolume, lastvolumeto: Double
    let lasttradeid: String
    let volumeday, volumedayto, volume24hour, volume24hourto: Double
    let openday, highday, lowday, open24hour: Double
    let high24hour, low24hour: Double
    let lastmarket: String
    let change24hour, changepct24hour, changeday, changepctday: Double
    let supply, mktcap, totalvolume24h, totalvolume24hto: Double

}

struct USDDisplay: Codable {
    let fromsymbol, tosymbol, market, price, lastupdate: String
    let lastvolume, lastvolumeto, lasttradeid, volumeday, volumedayto, volume24hour, volume24hourto : String
    let openday, highday, lowday, open24hour, high24hour, low24hour, lastmarket: String
    let change24hour, changepct24hour, changeday, changepctday: String
    let supply, mktcap, totalvolume24h, totalvolume24hto: String
}
```

---

To get rid of specifying all CodingKeys and make the keys lowercased create a helper struct (*stolen* from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/custom))

```
struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
        self.intValue = nil
    }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.stringValue = String(intValue)
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
}
```

Pass the custom `keyDecodingStrategy` and a suitable `dateDecodingStrategy` to the decoder

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .custom({ AnyKey(stringValue: $0.last!.stringValue.lowercased())!}) 
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
let coinList = try decoder.decode(CoinList.self, from: data)
print(coinList)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can you please tell how to overcome with the following error ""Expected to decode String but found a number instead." in lasttradeid? and one more thing it is working with the test.json but not from the response from the server

Comment: In the given URL all `lasttradeid` values are `String`. But if this could happen unfortunately you have to add the huge `init(from decoder` method to handle the cases.

Comment: can you please tell why it is not working with the server response?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Alamofire. Is the line to remove backslashes really necessary? I'd try `responseData` directly.

Comment: same problem if I remove the line :(

Comment: Replace `try?` with `try` and a `do catch` block and handle the error. Catching errors is indispensable while developing software.